# Why some strings are never translated on my android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, localization

I have an Android aplication with the default values/strings.xml and also a custom strings file values-pt/strings.xml (for Portuguese). This is working perfectly for **almost** every string on my application.

Just to make it clear, see the example below:

at **app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="button_install">Install</string>
```

at **app/src/main/res/values-pt/strings.xml**

```
<string name="button_install">Instalar</string>
```

The problem is that when i use the strings, somewhere like at a layout file, some strings are never translated. On the example below, the result is always "Install" and never "Instalar", even if the location is set to Pt.

```
<Button
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_install"
android:id="@+id/installBtn"
android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

The same doesn't happen to other buttons on the same layout,

Comment: I also have this problem! No answer yet ? :(